# what is the after element used for in JHBuild?

Tags: gnome, jhbuild

Can someone please tell me what the purpose of the after element in JHBuild is used for.
I've search far and wide for the description and I'm at a loss on why I cannot find anything about this.
Going on from this, I would like to know the difference between a dependencies, suggests, and after element. i.e. How does JHBuild treat these differently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

- **dependencies** are hard dependencies. Packages that are required to build a module.
- **suggests** are soft dependencies.  Packages might use them if they are installed (detected at build time) but if they are not present, they do not present a problem. These dependencies will be built, but they can be ignored without problems by using the argument *--ignore-suggests*.  For instance, evolution can be built with or without nss support.
- **after** are not strict dependencies, but they are needed at runtime to get some features.  For instance, metacity is needed by mutter to have key binding settings in mutter.